# Apply dynamic where clause to joined table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to build a LINQ query that allows me to vary the where clause on a joined table but can't find a way to do it.

A simplified example of the two queries I'm constructing are:

```
var myQuery = from tab1 in context.Table1
              join tab2 in context.Table2 on Table1.ID equals Table2.Table1ID
              where tab1.TypeCode == 3
                    tab2.SomeID == 4 &&  
              select tab1.ID;

var myQuery2 = from tab1 in context.Table1
              join tab2 in context.Table2 on Table1.ID equals Table2.Table1ID
              where tab1.TypeCode == 3
                    tab2.SomeOtherID == 4 &&  
              select tab1.ID;
```

The only difference between them being the tab2.SomeID where clause changes to tab2.SomeOtherID.

If the changing where clause was being applied to tab1 I could just add a .Where to the query but how do I use a common query and specify a different tab2 where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have optional parameters in queries:

```
int? someID = null;
int? someOtherID = 4;

var myQuery = from tab1 in context.Table1 
              join tab2 in context.Table2 on Table1.ID equals Table2.Table1ID 
              where tab1.TypeCode == 3 
               && (someID == null || tab2.SomeID == someID)
               && (someOtherID == null || tab2.SomeOtherID == someOtherID)
              select tab1.ID;
```

Linq-to-SQL will eliminate the parts that can be evaluated client-side from the query, so in the above example the where clause will filter on tab1.TypeCode and tab2.SomeOtherID.

Comment: I actually used that approach and thought that L2S would remove the redundant conditional. However it didn't and while having 1 == 0 in the SQL where wouldn't matter I was hoping there would be a cleaner way.

Comment: Check your query again - unless you used Linq-to-SQL's "CompiledQuery", L2S should eliminate the unnecessary parts of the query. (I.e. the parts that can be evaluated client-side)

Comment: L2S isn't that sophisitcated at elimintating unecessary parts of the query. I had to reduce the expressions is the LINQ to true or false to get them elimintated. Despite that this was the best approach I could find.

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

or

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/step2.png))</sub>

You need something like this? Use [the Linq Dynamic Query Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20081011004405/http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) (download includes examples).

Check out [ScottGu's blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) for more examples.

Comment: I've used DynamicLinq in the past to good effect but in this case I'd like to keep my query strongly typed.

Comment: than use PredicateBuilder will work for you link alreay there in answer